# how to make word > word(2) when input is word

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a google sheet cell I use as a inventory divided with commas
cell value-ex) banana, apple, grape

I want it to make it so that when

the input is banana,
cell value would be = banana(2), apple, grape

and if the input after that is banana,
cell value would be = banana(3), apple, grape
and so on.

How would you make banana > banana(2) and banana(2) > banana(3)?

-modified 22.04.05

I tried doing this

```
def add_item():
    text = "banana, apple, grape"
    added_item = input("> ")
    numBananas = 1
    items = text.split(', ')
    if added_item in items:
        numBananas += 1
        print(items)
        new_added_item = added_item + "(" + str(numBananas) + ")"
        print(new_added_item)
        items.append(new_added_item)
        items.remove(added_item)
        print(items)
        joined_string = ", ".join(items)
        print(joined_string)
    else: 
        items.append(added_item)
        print(items)
        joined_string = ", ".join(items)
        print(joined_string)

add_item()
```

when the input is 'grape',
outcome is : "banana, apple, grape(2)"

and when the input is 'durian',
outcome is: "banana, apple, grape, durian"

but the trouble is, when text is upgraded to

"banana, apple, grape(2)"

when the input after that is grape,

it becomes "banana, apple, grape(2), grape"

how can I make it so that it will be grape(3)?

Comment: What API/library are you using?

Comment: How is the input processed?  Does the user type directly into the cell, or is a python script providing the input, or what?

Comment: a python script is providing the input. sorry if my question was bad. I'm not that good with english.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not clear what api you're using, I'll show you what you can do in pure python and you can convert that as you wish.

```
numBananas = 1
SheetText = "banana, apple, grape"
while(True):
    x = input("> ")
    if(x == "banana"):
        numBananas += 1
    SheetText = "banana(" + numBananas + "), apple, grape"
    print(SheetText) #replace this with updating the API in your case
```

Sample Input:

```
banana
not a banana
Banana
banana
```

Sample Output:

```
banana(3), apple, grape
```

Comment: `numBananas++` is not valid python.  Also why do you have a semicolon?

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry, for some reason I mixed C++ and python... It's edited now.

Comment: Thanks! It's part of what I wanted. I tried making a code using this and modified my question. Would be nice if you check it out too!

Comment: @VEM If your question was solved you shouldn't edit it; you need to ask a new question based on your new requirements. If you have follow up questions that are very closely related you can keep them in the comment section. I'll try to take a look at your edits later today.